# How to parse this json string?

Tags: android, json

i want to parse this json.i have difficulty when i try to parse the following json.suggest me proper way of parsing following json.i edit my code ,noe this is the correct code that i want to parse.

```
  {
"tag":{
    "tag1":1,
    "tag2": "colour",
    "tag3":"value",
    "tag4":"value",
    "tag5":1,
    "tag6":1,
    "tag7":true,
    "tag8": [
            {
            "t1":"Red",
            "t2":"int",
            "t3":1,
            "t4":true
            },
            {
            "t1":"Green",
            "t2":"int",
            "t3":2,
            "t4":true
            },
            {
            "t1":"Blue",
            "t2":"int",
            "t3":3,
            "t4":true
            }
             ],
    "tag9":null,
    "tag10":1
},
"tag":{
    "tag1":2,
    "tag2": "value",
    "tag3":"value",
    "tag4":"value",
    "tag5":1,
    "tag6":1,
    "tag7":true,
    "tag8": [
            {
            "t1":"value",
            "t2":"value",
            "t3":true,
            "t4":true,

            },
            {
            "t1":"value",
            "t2":"value",
            "t3":false,
            "t4":true,

            }
             ],
    "tag9":1,
    "tag10":3
},
"tag":{
    "tag1":5,
    "tag2": "value",
    "tag3":"value",
    "tag4":"value",
    "tag5":1,
    "tag6":1,
    "tag7":false,
    "tag8": null,
    "tag9":null,
    "tag10":null
}

}

i had used this code        
    try {
        JSONObject json= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(loadJSONFromAsset()).nextValue();
        JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("tag");
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            int tag1 = (Integer) json2.get("tag1");
            String tag2 = (String) json2.get("tag2");
            String tag3 = (String) json2.get("tag3");
            String tag4 = (String) json2.get("tag4");
            int tag5 = (Integer) json2.get("tag5");
            int tag6 = (Integer) json2.get("tag6");
            boolean tag7 = json2.getBoolean("tag7");
            if (!json2.isNull("tag8")) {
                JSONArray jArray = json2.getJSONArray("tag8");
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jArray.length(); i1++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i1);
                    String Label = json_data.getString("t1");
                    String ValueType = json_data.getString("t2");
                    int Value = json_data.getInt("t3");
                    boolean isNextEnabled = json_data.getBoolean("t4");
                }
            }
            int previous = 0;
            if (!json2.isNull("tag9")) {

                 previous= (Integer) json2.get("tag9");
            }
            int next = 0;
            if (!json2.isNull("tag10")) {

                next = (Integer) json2.get("tag10");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("myjson");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
}
```

i get only last record ,how do i get all data .any help will be appreciated thanks...

Comment: Are all these dynamic or fixed?-> "tag" and tag1, tag2, t1,t2, "responses"

Comment: There are redundant `tag` keys, are you sure this is your JSON because even `JsonValidator` also returns the last `tag` key only.

Comment: You can try this parser https://jsonparser.online/ to verify JSON data online

Answer (score 0):

The JSONOject has a constructor that accepts a string of JSON data.  You can use the constructor to parse the JSON string.  If the string is valid JSON data, the constructor will return a JSONObject.  If the string is NOT valid JSON, the constructor will throw an error.  It's good practice to wrap the constructor inside of a try/catch block.

```
String json = "{name:\"value\"}";
JSONObject item = null;
try{
  item = new JSONObject(json);
}catch(Exception exc){
  Log.d(TAG, exc.toString());
}
if(item != null){
  Log.d(TAG, String.format("name:%s", item.getString("name")));
}
```

Comment: Consider adding explanation. Plain code rarely helps in the long run.

Comment: Good point. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse your string @ http://json.parser.online.fr/ it works nice for me.

From static review of the JSON string it seems you have "tag" element 3 times in your input and due to that parser might get confused. Try to remove duplicate entries and then try.